# Average number of stickers to complete an album

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

Suppose I have a sticker album which consists of $N$ stickers.  How many stickers should I buy in average to complete this album, assuming all the stickers appear with the same frequency?

More formally, let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be independent random variables with an uniform distribution on the set $\{1, 2, \dots N\}$.  Then, what is the expected value of the random variable
$$
Z=\min {\left\{n\in\mathbb N: \forall i\leq N,\,\,\exists m\leq n:\, X_m=i\right\}}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have $N-k$ and just need the last $k$, the probability that a sticker will be one you need is $k/N,$ so the expected number of stickers until that happens is $N/k$. Thus the total expected number of stickers is $$N \sum_{k=1}^N \dfrac1k$$